# "The happiness of your life depends upon the quality of your thoughts..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotations

> “The happiness of your life depends upon the quality of your thoughts:
>   therefore, guard accordingly, and take care that you entertain no
>   notions unsuitable to virtue and reasonable nature.”
>
> [Marcus Aurelius]

Guard what? "the happiness" or "the quality of your thoughts"?

Is nature reasonable????

"Take care that you entertain no notions" = "Take care that you don't entertain notions"?

Comment: Bear in mind that this is a translation of an ancient text, You should provide a citation.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **guard** is being used intransitively there. It is an admonition. It might be paraphrased as "look out" or "watch out" or "be vigilant".

Comment: and the word "accordingly" there? Does it mean "in a way that is suitable or right for the situation"?

Comment: Yes. That is what it means.

Answer (score 0):

> Guard what? "the happiness" or "the quality of your thoughts"?

**Guard** your thoughts because the happiness of your life depends on it.

> Is nature reasonable????

In this context, it just means that you should maintain good thoughts.

> "Take care that you entertain no notions" = "Take care that you don't
>   entertain notions"?

Yes